# DateTime.ParseExact function is not working as expected?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to parse following datetime string `"2016-05-31T16:03:39.5173279Z"` and receiving result is not what I would expect, I would expect that hour would be 16 not 18.

Here is a code:

```
string _UtcFormat= "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ";
DateTime.ParseExact("2016-05-31T16:03:39.5173279Z", _UtcFormat, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Any comments

[image]

Comment: Im guessing the machine running this is `UTC+2`?

Comment: At `16:03` UTC on May 31, 2016, it was `18:03` in Germany (their summertime is UTC+2).

Comment: @Jamiec Don't think so, see: (UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague

Comment: @krul Daylight saving time adds another hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` as the last argument of `DateTime.ParseExact()`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-05-31T16:03:39.5173279Z", _UtcFormat, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: The `.Kind` property of the value will be `Utc` after that which may not be what the asker needs.

Answer (score 4):

The bit you've perhaps not noticed is

```
Kind: Local
```

By default, `ParseExact` will parse the datetime and convert it to your local timezone.

If you want to ignore that, use the [overload which allows you to specify `DateTimeStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(v=vs.110).aspx) - I believe the setting you want is `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`

Comment: The `.Kind` property of the value will be `Utc` after that which may not be what the asker needs.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - except thats *exactly* what the asker asked for ?!?

Comment: Not sure. Do you think he considers this to be 16:03 UTC or 16:03 German summertime? I any case, the string probably comes from `.ToString("O")` on another `DateTime` value. When you `.ToString("O")` the result will depend on the `Kind`. So if we wants to round-trip, your solution is correct. And in that case maybe he should not supply the long `_UtcFormat` himself. It will only confuse him. However, if we wants to "fix" the wrong `Kind` of the original value, it is more natural to disregard the `Z` present in the string, like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the `Z`, as in:

```
string _UtcFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'";
```

At 16:03 UTC on May 31, 2016, it was 18:03 in Germany (their summertime is UTC+2).

In a date and time format string, the symbol `Z` has a special meaning. If you just want to see it as a character with no function, quote it as `'Z'` within the format string.